# Comparing the distribution of few integers

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions

Suppose every person in a group ranks the quality of two products. The quality can be ranked as 1 (very good), 2, 3, 4 and 5 (very bad). I have a list of those observations. which is the right way for me to compare if the quality of products A and B has the same distribution? And how can I implement it in Stata?

Comment: Mann-Whitney test.

Comment: I do not see how a Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon rank sum test would apply to this paired design. Also, as mentioned in my Answer, a Wilcoxon signed rank test seems problematic because Likert data will show many ties.

Comment: Ah... if these are *paired* observations (i.e. the same subject gets both A and B), then you would use the sign rank test (`signrank` in Stata). In either case the null hypothesis and alternate hypothesis is the same: $H_{0}: P(X_{A} > X_{B}) = 0.5; H_{A}: P(X_{A} > X_{B}) \ne 0.5$

Answer (score -2):

This seems to be a paired design: each subject tests both Product A and Product B.
Suppose you have $n = 70$ subjects. Also, suppose that B is somewhat worse than A, to
the extent that occasional subjects give B a slightly higher (less favorable)
score, while very occasional subjects give A a slightly higher score.

Fake data for our experimentation here might be generated as follows:

```
set.seed(1887); m = 70
A = sample(1:5, m, rep=T, p=c(2,2,1,1,0))
d = sample(-1:1, m, rep=T, p=c(1,4,2))  # 1/7 like B better; 2/7 like A better
B = pmin(A+d, 5)

summary(A);  summary(B);  summary(B-A)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.  ## A
  1.000   1.000   2.000   1.943   2.000   4.000 
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.  ## B
    0.0     1.0     2.0     2.1     3.0     4.0 
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.  ## B-A
-1.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.1571  1.0000  1.0000
```

A Wilcoxon signed rank test on differences `B - A` would not work well because
of the preponderance of ties and 0's. Also, there are very few different integer values in `B - A` so that it seems too much of a stretch to assume normality and do a t test.

A tally of B-A is as follows:

```
table(B-A)

-1  0  1 
 8 43 19
```

That is, among those who indicated any difference between A and B, 19 out of 27
preferred A.

A 'sign test' or 'binomial test' assesses whether equally preferred products A and B would show such a distribution of lower and higher scores, the null hypothesis. In R, the procedure `binom.test`, with a 2-sided alternative, gives the following results:

```
binom.test(19, 27)

        Exact binomial test

data:  19 and 27
number of successes = 19, number of trials = 27, p-value = 0.05224
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4981863 0.8624734
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.7037037
```

The P-value slightly greater than 5% shows that we do not have evidence that
the products differ in favorability at the 5% level. In R, the P-value is computed from
the binomial CDF `pbinom` as shown below:

```
2*(1-pbinom(18, 27, .5))
[1] 0.05223899
```

However, suppose B is a cheapened version of A and you anticipated that B would be rated worse than A, if anything. Then a one-sided test would be appropriate, as shown below. It shows significance at the 5% level.

```
binom.test(19, 27, alte="g")

        Exact binomial test

data:  19 and 27
number of successes = 19, number of trials = 27, p-value = 0.02612
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is greater than 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.5286085 1.0000000
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.7037037
```

*Notes:* (a) For this illustration I have chosen fake data that shows relatively little difference between products. If there were a more substantial difference, then 70 subjects would likely show a significant difference in the two-sided test. (b) [This page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BSDA/versions/1.2.0/topics/SIGN.test)
shows documentation for the R procedure `SIGN.test` (not in base R), which would
accept the vector `B-A` as input [instead of counts derived from this vector, as for `binom.test`.] (c) It has been some time since I used Stata; the first thing to check is whether it implements a 'sign test' to your satisfaction. For promising links, google `sign test Stata`. Otherwise, you can use its binomial PDF function to find P-values.

*Addendum:* As I mentioned earlier, the Wilcoxon signed-rank test is of questionable value here because there are so few unique values in the difference B-A. In my example, three: $-1, 0, 1,$ mostly $0$'s, so that that nothing is
lost using the sign test. In general with differences in Likert scores, there can be very
few unique non-zero values unless differences of opinion about A and B are profound.

```
length(unique(B-A))
[1] 3

wilcox.test(B-A)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  B - A
V = 266, p-value = 0.03545
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0

Warning messages:
1: In wilcox.test.default(B - A) : cannot compute exact p-value with ties
2: In wilcox.test.default(B - A) :
  cannot compute exact p-value with zeroes
```

If there were only a few ties or 0's, maybe I'd be willing to trust the approximate value given, but this situation presents extreme cases. Then claims in a proprietary
technical bulletin that all is well could hardly be persuasive.

Artificially breaking ties by slight jittering (as with `wilcox.test(B-A+runif(70,-.1,.1))`) gave P-values from .03 to .46 in a dozen tries, only two
of them below 5%. I believe power is not being 'hemoraged'; it was never
there.

Perhaps a permutation test would have
better power than a sign test, but there can't be many unique medians in a
permutation distribution.

Comment: The sign test hemorrhages statistical power relative to the sign rank test because it discard information about the (ranked) magnitude of the differences.

Comment: True, but here there are too many ties and 0's for the signed rank test.

Comment: Stata's signed rank test implementation adjusts for both zeros and ties out of the box. Article on it: Sribney, W. M. (1995). Correcting for ties and zeros in sign and rank tests. *Stata Technical Bulletin*, 26:2–4.

Comment: An exact Wilcoxon signed-rank test in the presence of ties is provided by the `exactRankTests` package for R. (For your example it should result in exactly the same p-value as the sign test.) Nevertheless, there are a couple of reasons one might prefer a sign test, though I think you've not quite put your finger on them. First, the null hypothesis for the Wilcoxon signed-rank test is that the ranked differences are symmetric around nought - but asymmetry needn't result from A's being better than B (or vice versa) in any sense. ...

Comment: ... Second, to rank differences you need to be able to take differences - getting around this by first transforming "very good" &c. into ranks isn't always what you'd want to do. The sign test doesn't require a decision about whether '1' for A & '3' for B is a difference of larger or smaller magnitude than '5' for A & '4' for B.

Comment: Thank you all. I conducted a signrank test in Stata. The outpout of signrank V2ACC= VLC was 
Ho: V2ACC = VLC
             z =  -9.332
    Prob > |z| =   0.0000
I think this must be a two-sided test, but just wanted to confirm this?

Comment: @JosuéOrtega: Glad to hear of your progress with this! Please let's not get too far into analysis of _fake_ data I used as an exmp in my Answ, and focus on _your real_ data. My experience with paired Likert data is one can't rely on more precision than whether Subject Nr. 15 liked A or B better with _maybe_ some crude idea how much better. In my (continuing) view, such data is usually best handled by a sign test unless you have great faith in small diff's in opinion. // Did a permutation test w/ diff in means as metric, P-val aprx 0.001, but not sure means are meaningful summary for real dta.